# Javascript - Onclick en enlaces

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Mi duda es: ¿se pueden hacer eventos onclicks en enlaces ?

cambiar_estado.php

```
$query =    "SELECT 
                *   
            FROM
                usuarios_datos
            WHERE 
                ID_OBLIGATORIO = '".$_REQUEST["Id"]."'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    //Mientras existen datos, analizamos el ID asignado extrayendo su estado
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
        <center>
        <?php 
            if($row["estado"] == 0) {
                echo "<a href=\"javascript:cargaXML('cambiar_estado.php?Id=".$_REQUEST["Id"]."','estado".$_REQUEST["Id"]."')\">";
                    echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/0.gif\">";
                echo "</a>";
            } else if($row["estado"] == 1) {
                echo "<a href=\"javascript:cargaXML('cambiar_estado.php?Id=".$_REQUEST["Id"]."','estado".$_REQUEST["Id"]."')\">";
                    echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/1.gif\">";
                echo "</a>";
            } else {
                echo "<a href=\"javascript:cargaXML('cambiar_estado.php?Id=".$_REQUEST["Id"]."','estado".$_REQUEST["Id"]."')\">";
                    echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/2.gif\">";
                echo "</a>";
            }
        ?>
        </center>
    <?php 
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
```

index.php

```
echo "<td width=\"08%\" id=\"estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">" ?>
    <!-- Columna ESTADO del usuario.    -->
    <center>
    <?php
        $estado = 1;
        "<a href=\"javascript:cargaXML('cambiar_estado.php?Id=".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."','estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."')\">";
              echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/".$row['estado'].".gif\">";
        echo "</a>";
    ?>
    </center>
    <?php 
echo "</td>";
```

Bien mi pregunta es, en esos enlaces  puedo insertar un evento onclick para que al hacer click en la imagen .gif me pregunte (confirm()) si deseo mostrar imagen1.gif o imagen2.gif? Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Si se puede, onclick="return tuFuncion();" y ahi cargar el confirm

Comment: Sé que voy a sonar mal pero, ¿has intentado hacerlo? Te lleva menos tiempo probar a ver si se puede (sí se puede) que escribir la pregunta en SOes.

Comment: echo "<td width=\"08%\" id=\"estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">" ?>  
echo "<a href='#' onclick='return cambiar_estado();'\">";
          echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/".$row['estado'].".gif\">";
echo "</a>";
echo "</td>";

<script language="Javascript">
function cambiar_estado() {
    var texto = "";
    var pregunta = confirm("¿Qué deseas elegir?");
    if (pregunta == true) {
        texto = "¡Has presionado OK!";
    } else {
        texto = "¡Has presionado Cancelar!";
    }
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = texto;
}
</script>

¿Como asigno a cada id el texto?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function doClick(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 alert(this.innerHTML);
}
var aTags =  document.querySelectorAll('a');

for(var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++){
    aTags[i].addEventListener('click',doClick,false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href=""> click me</a>
  <a href=""> click me too</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Si puedes, una manera de hacerlo es agregar un *Listener* a las etiquetas

el *Listener* pasa como argumento un *Evento*, la clave está en `e.preventDefault()` ya que evita el comportamiento normal de la etiqueta